# Understanding Scala Upper bounds

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand why upperbound exists in Scala. This asn example code where they are trying to explain Upperbounds

```
class Animal
class Dog extends Animal
class Puppy extends Dog

class AnimalCarer{
  def display [T <: Dog](t: T){
    println(t)
  }
}

object ScalaUpperBoundsTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val animal = new Animal
    val dog = new Dog
    val puppy = new Puppy

    val animalCarer = new AnimalCarer

    //animalCarer.display(animal) uncommenting this line leads to an error
    animalCarer.display(dog)
    animalCarer.display(puppy)
  }
}
```

If the commented line is uncommented, you get an error. But you would still get the error if you changed the `display` method in `AnimalCarer` to

```
def display(t: Dog){
println(t)
}
```

So, what is the need to specifically tell the compiler that t should be a subtype of Dog?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. The `display` method take something that is a `Dog`. you are passing it an `Animal` shouldn't compile. Your suggested change to the method still doesn't allow an `Animal` to be passed because an `Animal` isn't a `Dog`. I don't understand your confusion

Comment: @pedromss : My confusion is that why do we have to give this syntax - "[T <: Dog](t: T)", when the compiler is intelligent enough to detect it by itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a rather useless example. You are right, `def display[T <: Dog](t: T)` is equivalent to just `def display(t: Dog)`, the type parameter serves no purpose.

We can change your example a little bit to make it more useful:

```
 def display[T <: Dog](t: T): T = {
    println(t)
    t
 }
```

Here the type parameter is useful, because if you pass in a `Poodle`, what you get back is still a `Poodle`, not just any `Dog`.

Comment: hmmm okay..but if this was the pupose, then isn't the name 'upper bounds' confusing? Because in your example ou are ensuring that you get back (return statement) the exact type that you passed as argument (your example of Poodle). Is this the sole purpose of 'upperbound'? Can you give more examples, if possible?

Comment: The purpose of type PARAMETER (`T`) in this case is to ensure you get back the same thing you passed in. The purpose of type BOUNDARY (`<: Dog`) is to ensure that what you pass in is a `Dog`, not a `Cat` or a `Parrot`